# Would like to limit the number of elements in a Pivot Chart filter

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-chart

I am creating a pivot table with a corresponding pivot chart in VBA.

I have filtered the data in the table to show only the top 5 values and the chart also only displays the top five values. However, if you click the field filter button on the chart, every value is there and checked by default (even though only five are visible).

The problem comes when I want to remove one of the top five from the chart (due to the fact that it is so large it is suppressing the visibility of the other data). If I unselect that item, suddenly every other item becomes visible instead of just the other four items like I would like. I realize this is because all the items are checked in the filter.

What I would like to know is why they are all checked by default even though only five are visible and if there is a workaround for this issue (can the filter only show the top five or at least only have the top five checked)?